# Removing duplicates according one column

Tags: r

My dummy data looks like this:

```
> head(dummy)
            C1          C2
[1,]         1           1
[2,]         1           2
[3,]         1           3
[4,]         2           3
[5,]         2           4
[6,]         2           5
```

Value `3` is duplicated in `C2`, but those lines are unique in data frame. I want to remove all duplicates according `C2` and keep only first/last occurrence  according `C1`.

Example of what I want:

```
> remove duplicates leave first in C1
            C1          C2
[1,]         1           1
[2,]         1           2
[3,]         1           3
[5,]         2           4
[6,]         2           5
# filtered    [4,]   2    3
```

Or

```
> remove duplicates leave first in C1
            C1          C2
[1,]         1           1
[2,]         1           2
[4,]         2           3
[5,]         2           4
[6,]         2           5
# filtered   [3,]   1    3
```

Comment: As function `duplicated` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if dat is the dataset

```
dat[with(dat, !duplicated(C2)),]
 C1 C2
1  1  1
2  1  2
3  1  3
5  2  4
6  2  5


dat[with(dat, !duplicated(C2,fromLast=TRUE)),]
```